# SerialPort - Clear Existing Data

Tags: .net, vb.net, serial-port

I'm using the .NET SerialPort class to communicate with gauges.  Every time a button on a gauge is pressed a reading value is sent over port.

The problem I have is that if the gauge button is pressed while the program is off then when the program starts it fires the data received event for that existing data.  I don't want this behavior -- I only want to collect readings done after the port is opened.

I have a current workaround using a Thread.Sleep but it seems hacky and I'm wondering if anyone knows of a better solution.

```
port = New SerialPort("COM1", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One)

port.Open()
port.DtrEnable = True

System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
port.ReadExisting()

AddHandler port.DataReceived, AddressOf PortDataReceived
```

If I don't have the Thread.Sleep then the DataReceived event is fired for the previous gauge data.  I'm guessing this is because the ReadExisting doesn't block and so when its called immediately after an open it just reads nothing.

Thanks

---

So if you call 'port.BytesToRead()' immediately after open its zero.  If you call it 100ms after open its non-zero.  I guess this makes sense -- it takes time after open to read the existing data.

Another option is to call read and set the read timeout but that seems no different than Thread.Sleep except you have to catch an exception...

Comment: Are you using Xon/Xoff or hardware handshaking

Comment: I'm using whatever the default is for the SerialPort class in .NET.  I'll try and figure out what that is :)

Comment: also do your serial devices buffer the button press and resend if there is no communications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 port.DtrEnable = True
```

That could have a side-effect.  The gauge might be jumping up and down, eager to send the reading.  After all, somebody pressed the button to tell it that it's okay to send.  But its transmit routine is observing the handshake protocol, Data Terminal Ready is not on.  Jump, jump, ah! it's on.  Send.  That takes a while, depends on the baudrate.

Well, why did somebody press the button even though the computer wasn't ready?  Why isn't it *always* ready?  Answer that question, then you can delete Sleep().  Also find out what happens when that somebody presses the button a hundred times before the computer is ready.  Your Sleep() might well be too short.

Comment: I'm not a serial port export.  Having DTR on results in a command being sent to the device on open?  If so that makes total sense.  (Without that line I never receive data btw).  Pressing it multiple times seems to make no difference -- it only stores 1 result until its read.  So off, press 10 times, on, I read 1 message from the gauge.  At least this particular gauge :)

Comment: To answer the second part (why press the button without the program on) -- I just want to handle inadvertent use.  Its a gauge calibration log program so they start it up to record values.  I just want to ensure there is no confusion -- they start the program up and don't see a value already entered.

Comment: Well, that's fine, nobody is going to particularly notice 100 milliseconds.  Nor will they complain when your program shows a reading after starting up, even though the button wasn't pressed since then.  This can't be a real problem.  Educate your users, they'll go "Ah, makes sense".

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to collect what is waiting in the out buffer of the serialport try calling the  <del>serialPort.DiscardWriteBuffer()</del> serialPort.DiscardOutBuffer() which should clear out whatever has collected there. Thanks to Chad for correcting my error.

Comment: Isn't it `serialPort.DiscardOutBuffer()`?